# Fix regex expression to have character limit

Tags: c#, regex

I want to limit the number of characters that a user can enter, but i'm sure how to do so due to the expression being complex.

I've got:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

I've tried:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*){0,30}*$
```

Comment: Are you sure it limits the characters to 30? I just tried and it didn't work for me. The expression is for names, to allow double barrel and names containing spaces etc

Comment: @Jimbob101 Does it have to be a regex pattern?

Comment: Why not just enforce the pattern with regex and count the string length if the pattern succeeded? Hint: `userInput.Length`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus with a little bit of an adjustment, yours worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some [Positive Lookup](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to test for the total length of the string like so:

```
^(?=.{0,30}$)[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is functionally equivalent to this, as manageable and
countable regex.

`^[a-zA-Z](?:[',. -](?=[a-zA-Z])|[a-zA-Z]){0,29}$`

```
 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z] 
 (?:
      [',. -] 
      (?= [a-zA-Z] )
   |  
      [a-zA-Z] 
 ){0,29}
 $
```